# Select latest 2 products from each category on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, select, scope

I have a PRODUCTS model with 3 columns: ID, NAME and CATEGORY What i would like to know now is if it's at all possible to select 2 products for each distinct category with rails 3.2.

The order of the selected products is of no importance, they might as well be random. But it's important that i only have max 2 products per category.

Answer (score 0):

Associations in models:

**product.rb**

```
belongs_to :categories
```

**category.rb**

```
has_many :projects
```

**controller:**

```
@categories = Category.all
```

**view:**

```
<% @categories.each do |categorie| %>
  <%= categorie.name %> has
  <% categorie.products.limit(2).each do |product| %>
    <%= product.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i need 2 products for each all categories... display every category 2 products